# CSS table properties to maximise cell width

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have this in my CSS:

```
ES{
max-width:20px;
word-wrap:break-word;

}
```

And my table looks like this...

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" class="ES" >
<tr>
    <td><input name="rbeso" type="radio" id="rblimpet" value="limpet" title="Seafood" /><b>The Doctor Limpet</b> Fresh from the sea! Crab flakes, alfredo sauce and mozzarella cheese.</td>


</tr>
```

I want the cells to have the max width but it doesn't seem to make a difference...

Comment: `.ES`, not `ES`. The rule you have matches against `<es>`, not `<foobar class="es">`

Comment: dear see my answer and make the correction in your code your problem will solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo:

```
.ES {
^--missing
```

without the `.`, you're defining a css rule for some non-existing `<es>` tag, not a CSS class.

Answer (score 1):

see fiddle for code and demo

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RwXkz/

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RwXkz/embedded/result/

Screen shot: http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/1528/80290481.jpg

Answer (score 0):

To define a style for the  elements based on the class of table you want something like:

```
.ES td{
max-width:20px;
word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

I don't think you need the word-wrap attribute, it should break by default.

If you are still having trouble with the width of the columns after this change, you might want to explicitly specify the width of the columns (not "max-width" but "width") and you can also mess around with these attributes at the table / "ES" style.

```
table.ES, .ES { width: 300px; }
```

OR

```
table.ES, .ES { width: 100%; }
```

Generally it's an advantage of the table that the columns will dynamically generate the appropriate width depending upon the column contents.

You may want to specify a width on columns that you know are you going to be small, specify a width for the table, and let the columns with larger field values auto-adjust their width.